# Limiting the number of characters of user input

Tags: c++, input, user-input, cin

I'm trying to limit # of characters a user can input.
It's not like when user inputs *abcde*, and I limit the input length to be 3,
and only *abc* is taken into account.

Is there a way to *physically* limit user from inputting more than certain amount of characters?
For example, if user trys to type *12345*, and if I limit it to 3 characters, only *123* gets typed.

I've tried the following code:

> cin.width(5);
>   cin >> n;

But I've realized it doesn't *physically* limit the user input, but only limits the buffersize of input.

Is there a way to do something like this?

+) I'm working on Console Application

Comment: You could read each key and then do the processing when the user types `\r` or at 3. But that wouldn't block the extra characters (it would simply accept 3 characters as the users input and move on without waiting for a `\r`).

Comment: Hmm, I wish I could do something like this.

Comment: What do you mean by _physically_? You want a hand to come out of the screen and slap the user when she attempts to type 4-th character ? :)

Comment: @tony I had no idea how else to describe it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a standard console window but if you use c++ to make your own window with your own input box then you have some more flexibility.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: @Haxify Ofcourse! many games are programmed in c++ and have similar restrictions for some parts (such as username selection). However you cant really do this with out of the box c++. You need to find yourself a library. Oh and I meant to say you *cant* do it in a console. Sorry, typo.

Comment: I could make it work in a console. It wouldn't be as pretty as it could be, but it wouldn't be hard.

Comment: @chris Then you should post the outline of the answer.

Comment: @Dgrin91, I don't know... It might do more harm than good and it'd be Windows-only.

Answer (score 2):

You could do some weird thing like reading individual characters one at a time, and if they don't hit return by the 4th character, say invalid input and then make them start over, but it's cleaner and easier to just call long input invalid after they try to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be searching for this:--

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string MyInput;
    std::cout << "INPUT HERE: ";
    std::getline(cin,MyInput);
    if (MyInput.length() == 3)
    {
        std::cout << "OKAY IT IS THREE CHARS" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (!(MyInput.length() == 3))
    {
        MyInput.erase(MyInput.begin()+3,MyInput.end());
        std::cout << "Look: " << MyInput << std::endl;
    }
}
```